# How do we show that equivalence?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

We have the triangle ABC. We have that $X\in AC$, $Y\in BC$ and $Z=AY\cap BX$, where $X,Y\neq A,B,C$. I want to show that AB is parallel to XY iff $\frac{|CX|}{|CA|}=\frac{|ZB|}{|ZX|}=1$.

Could you give me a hint what we have to show?

When $AB$ is parallel to $XY$ then we have that then $AZB$ and $ZXY$ are congruent. What do we get from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively: if $CA=CX$ and $ZB=ZX$, then $CZ||AB$. Then $XY \cap AB$ is not empty, so the hypothesis is not valid.

Comment: So, is it wrong that $\frac{|CX|}{|CA|}=\frac{|ZB|}{|ZX|}=1$ ? Should the statement maybe be without equal to $1$ ?

Comment: Apparently under the given conditions it is impossible to make $XY$ and $AB$ parallel. I think even if the equal to $1$ is removed, it will not change. Analyze the solutions suggested here to understand the issue.

Comment: One option is $\frac{CX}{CA}=\frac{XZ}{ZB}$.

Comment: We have that the triangles $AZB$ and $ZXY$ are similar, so we get that $\frac{BZ}{ZX}=\frac{AZ}{ZY}=\frac{AB}{XY}$. We also have that the triangles $ABC$ and $XYC$ are similar, so we get that $\frac{XY}{AB}=\frac{YC}{BC}=\frac{XC}{AC}$. From these two relations we get that  $\frac{BZ}{ZX}=\frac{AC}{XC}$, right? What about the other direction? When it holds that $\frac{BZ}{ZX}=\frac{AC}{XC}$ can we conclude that $XY$ and $AB$ are parallel?

Comment: Yes, you got it right. For other direction, one method is you can take a point $Y'\in BC$ so that $XY'||AB$ and show $Y'=Y$.

Comment: For this direction we assume that it holds that $\frac{BZ}{ZX}=\frac{AC}{XC} \Rightarrow \frac{BZ}{AC}=\frac{ZX}{XC}$. But if we assume an other point $Y'$ what relation do we get? If instead of that we have that $X'Y||AB$ for a point $X'\in AC$, we have that $\frac{BZ}{ZX'}=\frac{AZ}{ZY}=\frac{AB}{X'Y}$ and that $\frac{X'Y}{AB}=\frac{YC}{BC}=\frac{X'C}{AC}$. Therefore we have that $\frac{BZ}{ZX'}=\frac{AC}{X'C}$ and so we get that $\frac{BZ}{AC}=\frac{ZX'}{X'C}$. Therefore, we get that $\frac{ZX}{XC}=\frac{ZX'}{X'C}$. Is this correct so far? But can we conclude from here that $X=X'$ ?

Comment: I don't think you can claim $\frac{BZ}{ZX'}=\frac{AZ}{ZY}$, because the triangles $ABZ, ZX'Y$ may not be similar in general.

Comment: Ah because $Z$ is the intersection of $AY$ and $BX$ and not of $AY$ and $BX'$, right?

Comment: Yes. If $Y'$, then $\frac{CX}{CA}=\frac{ZX}{ZB}=\frac{XY'}{AB}$. If $XY'\ne XY\iff \frac{CX}{CA}\ne \frac{ZX}{ZB}.$ Good luck.

Comment: We have that the triangles $ABZ$ and $XZY'$ are similar, and so $\frac{BZ}{ZX}=\frac{AZ}{ZY'}=\frac{AB}{XY'}$ and also the triangles $ABC$ and $Y'XC$ are similar and so we get that $\frac{XY'}{AB}=\frac{Y'C}{BC}=\frac{XC}{AC}$, right? Therefore we get that $\frac{CX}{CA}=\frac{ZX}{ZB}=\frac{XY'}{AB}$. But why does it hold that $XY'\ne XY\iff \frac{CX}{CA}\ne \frac{ZX}{ZB}$ ?

Comment: Because $\frac{CX}{CA}$ and $AB$ do not change and $\frac{ZX}{ZB}$ will change with the change of $XY'$.

Comment: We consider the point $Y'\in B$ so that $AB\parallel XY'$. Then there is a new intersection point $Z'$ of $AY'$ and $BX$. We get then that $\frac{BZ'}{Z'X}=\frac{AZ'}{Z'Y'}=\frac{AB}{XY'}$ and $\frac{XY'}{AB}=\frac{Y'C}{BC}=\frac{XC}{AC}$. So, we get that $\frac{BZ'}{Z'X}=\frac{AC}{XC}$. For this direction we assume that it holds that $\frac{BZ}{ZX}=\frac{AC}{XC}$. So we have that $\frac{BZ'}{Z'X}=\frac{BZ}{ZX}$. That means that $Z'=Z$. This holds only when $Y'=Y$. That means that it must hold that $AB\parallel XY$. Is everything correct?

Comment: I think it is correct. Slightly different but better explanation than mine. Typo: $Y'\in BC$.

Comment: Is it correct that from $\frac{BZ'}{Z'X}=\frac{BZ}{ZX}$ we get that $Z'=Z$ ?

Comment: Yes, since $Z\in BX, Z'\in BX$.

Comment: Ah ok!! Thank you very much!! :-)

Answer (score 3):

If $\frac{CX}{CA}=1$ then $C$ is a midpoint of $AX$.

Now, since $AB||XY$, we obtain that $ABXY$ is parallelogram and $AY\cap BX=\oslash$

Comment: Can $ABXY$ be a trapezium?

Comment: So we suppoe that $X$ is outside of the side $AC$, right?

Comment: @farruhota No, because $AC=CX$.

Comment: @Mary Star Yes, because we need $CX=CA$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was focusing on my method (below) when $AY$ and $BX$ intersect and $XY$ is not parallel to $AB$.

Comment: So, is it inly possible if $X$ outside of $AC$ ? If we have had instead of $\frac{|CX|}{|CA|}=\frac{|ZB|}{|ZX|}=1$ just $\frac{|CX|}{|CA|}=\frac{|ZB|}{|ZX|}$ (without equal to $1$), could it then be inside the side? @MichaelRozenberg